# GeoJSON from PostGIS for Vector

Tags: postgis

Based on the following code block:

```
var SphericalMercator = require('sphericalmercator');
var mercator = new SphericalMercator({
    size: 256
})

var bbox = mercator.bbox(
   +req.params.x,
   +req.params.y,
   +req.params.z,
   false,
   '4326');
var test_query = 'SELECT st_asgeojson(wkb_geometry) AS feature FROM ogrgeojson where 
ST_INTERSECTS(wkb_geometry, ' + bbox + ')';
```

I run this as a query and get the following error:

```
error: function st_intersects(geometry, numeric, numeric, numeric, numeric) does not exist]

hint: 'No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.'
```

I am not sure how I should be wrapping the bbox. Additionally things that I have tried have resulted in column errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
var point      = 'ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(' + 
                   req.params.x + ',' + 
                   req.params.y + '),4326)';
var test_query = 'SELECT st_asgeojson(wkb_geometry) AS feature ' + 
                 'FROM ogrgeojson WHERE ' +
                 'ST_INTERSECTS(wkb_geometry, ' + point + ')';
```

Comment: Your answer is code only, please add addition description.

Comment: Paul solution works great. The thing is , please check postgis function: http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersects.html . Input information for this function is (geometry, geometry), and from shkfnly's code the function is receiving (geometry, numeric, numeric, numeric, numeric)

Comment: Right, his "box" is spooling out to number,number,number,number when JS runs tostring on it, hence the funny signature it ends up trying to call in the db.

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering I realized that I had to encode the bbox in an ST_MakeEnvelope call: [postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeEnvelope.html](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeEnvelope.html). This is because the call to mercator simply returns a conversion from the point being represented to the [minLng, minLat, maxLng, maxLat]. I can use ST_MakeEnvelope to return the proper PostGIS type based on this input. Code is as follows.

```
var test_query = 'SELECT st_asgeojson(wkb_geometry) AS feature 
                  FROM ogrgeojson
                  WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(wkb_geometry, ST_MakeEnvelope('+ bbox + ', 4326))';
```